# Can't paginate from Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, pagination

I've been using Laravel just for a few days so this is a newbie question. I'm trying a lot of things but I can't paginate my results...

I've tried

```
$productos = Producto::paginate(8);
```

instead of

```
 $productos = Producto::get();
```

and I got the first 8 results but I can't use links method to paginate, getting a

> 'Method links doesn't exist'

error

```
public function totalProductos() {

       $productos = Producto::get();
       $productos = $productos->sortByDesc(function ($productos){
       return $productos->detalles->sum('cantidad');

       });  

        return view('admin.usuarios.rankingproductos')->with(compact('productos'));

}
```

Using that code I got all the results but I need a few pages to order them. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
public function totalProductos() {

   $productos = Producto::paginate(8);
   $productos = $productos->sortByDesc(function ($productos){
   return $productos->detalles->sum('cantidad');

   });  

    return view('admin.usuarios.rankingproductos')->with(compact('productos'));

 }
```

Your view file like:

```
<div class="pull-left">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="explore-pagination">
              <nav>
                <div class="pagination"> {{ $productos->render() }}</div>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
```

**Updated Answer**

```
public function totalProductos() {

   $productos = Producto::sortByDesc(function ($productos){
   return $productos->detalles->sum('cantidad');

   })->paginate(8);;  

    return view('admin.usuarios.rankingproductos')->with(compact('productos'));

 }

<div class="pull-left">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="explore-pagination">
                  <nav>
                    <div class="pagination"> {{ $productos->links() }}</div>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>   
          </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried before posting but I got a 'Method render does not exist.' error :(

Comment: Method links does not exist

Comment: @VíctorGV: Please run clear the cache and view then try

Comment: Nope... i think the problem is waht I want to paginate is a collection.

Comment: @VíctorGV: Okay

Answer (score 1):

**Update answer**

```
public function totalProductos() {

   $productos = Producto::paginate(8)->sortByDesc(function ($productos){
   return $productos->detalles->sum('cantidad');

   });  

    return view('admin.usuarios.rankingproductos', compact(['productos']));

 }
```

**'Method links doesn't exist'**

The `links` method will render the links to the rest of the pages in the result set. Each of these links will already contain the proper `page` query string variable.

So, once you have retrieved the results, you may display the results and render the page links on your `blade` file

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($productos as $product)
        {{ $product->name }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $productos->links() }}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried before posting but I got a 'Method links does not exist.' error :(

Comment: It desn't work. I think the problem is what I want to paginate is a collection. Not sure how to get it... I'll take a look googling again Thanks, anyway

Comment: You are welcome man!!! I think you need using instead sortByDesc sortBy

Comment: The main thing you just logic have into your code not properly  $productos->detalles->sum()

Answer (score 1):

controller function is:

```
public function totalProductos() {

       $productos = Producto::paginate(8)->sortByDesc(function ($productos){
       return $productos->detalles->sum('cantidad');

       });  

        return view('admin.usuarios.rankingproductos')->with(compact('productos'));

     }
```

you should write this line `{!! $productos->render() !!}` in blade file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         {!! $productos->render() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case I got this error message :(       (1/1) BadMethodCallException

Method paginate does not exist.
in Macroable.php line 74
at Collection->__call('paginate', array(8))in ProductoController.php line 169
at ProductoController->totalProductos()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ProductoController), 'totalProductos'), array())in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('totalProductos', array())in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(ProductoController), 'totalProductos')in Route.php line 203